# Why do i get the following error? "Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: SHOW TABLES"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, capybara, factory-bot

Using Spork, Rails3, RSpec2, Capybara, and FactoryGirl.

While trying to execute a Capybara test I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: model = FactoryGirl.create(:model)
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
      Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: SHOW TABLES
```

The MySQL database that database.yml is using, is up and running. I can connect to it from the command line using the same settings in database.yml.

The tests were working fine, I was trying to figure out why a test was failing and then it started giving this error.

I've tried shutting down and restarting the database to no avail.

**From database.yml**

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_app_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

**From my spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Model", :js => true do

  before(:each) do
    model = FactoryGirl.create(:model)
    visit model_path(model)
  end

  it "should show the button" do
    # Start the lesson
    find("#startButton")
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

It's also important to mention that I have been using [solution 3](http://pastie.org/1745020) to the [Capybara Transactional Fixtures Issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ruby-capybara/JI6JrirL9gM/R6YiXj4gi_UJ) associated with non Rack::Test drivers.

I had placed my solution in my **spec_helper.rb** file like so:

```
Spork.prefork do
  ...
  class ActiveRecord::Base
    mattr_accessor :shared_connection
    @@shared_connection = nil

    def self.connection
      @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
    end
  end

  ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  ...
end
```

I had heard that there were similar [issues when using solution 3 with spork](http://opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/#comment-815) in a comment on [solution 2](http://opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/#comment-220). I'm not sure if these are the issues the commenter mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried running the SHOW TABLES command from the command line?

Comment: Yeah, I can log into Mysql with the same user/password/database and run SHOW TABLES. Works as expected.

Comment: I see an issue raised on the MySQL2 github: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/209

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have figured this out. I was unable to find a solution on the web, so I'll document here in case anyone else is googling around for that error message.

I think the issue is that Spork was caching/keeping around a closed MySQL connection.

This is because the implementation of **Solution 3** above is sitting in the **Spork.prefork** definition. So it will only be run once when Spork launches. Killing and Restarting Spork will temporarily resolve the issue. However the issue will come back if another MySQL connection is closed in the new Spork process.

The permanent fix is to move the **Solution 3** in your spec_helper.rb file into the **Spork.each_run** definition in the same file. So your spec_helper.rb file should look like this:

```
Spork.prefork do
  ...
  ...
end

Spork.each_run do
  ...
  class ActiveRecord::Base
    mattr_accessor :shared_connection
    @@shared_connection = nil

    def self.connection
      @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
    end
  end

  ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  ...
end
```

This seems to have worked for me. 
Cheers!

Comment: I've found that just moving this part: `ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection` to the `each_run` block does the trick (the rest can stay in the `prefork` block)